# UITableView inside UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

This should be straight foreward, but I simply can't figure it out(!)

I have a UIView 'filled with' a UIScrollView. Inside the scrollView I wan't to have a UITableView.

I have hooked up both the scrollView and the tableView with IBOutlet's in IB and set the ViewController to be the delegate and datasource of the tableView.

What else do I need to do ?  Or what shouldn't I have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `UITableView` is already an `UIScrollView`. Why do you need to add an additional one between your top view and your table?

Just remove the `UIScrollView` and it will work better than before :)

Comment: Because I have a background image on my window and I want my tableView to be smaller in width than my view, så that the background image can be seen on the sides.

The tableview won't be scrollable, but might become much longer than the screen - therefor I want to be able to scroll down feeling that I'm sliding it on top of the background image, by scrolling the UIScrollView under the tableView instead of scrolling the table it self.....

Comment: I would suggest you to customize the `UITableView` without trying to achieve what you want to do by forbid scrolling of table while providing it with an additional scroll view in the middle. Take a look here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `UITableView` next to the `UIScrollView` (as a sibling, not a child). Then use `scrollViewDidScroll` (or `layoutSubviews` in case of a subclass) to synchronise the vertical position of both scrollviews.